# Timeshift and btrfs. Recovery unable to mount /home

Tags: mount, btrfs, recovery

I am using btrfs (which seems integral to the question).

Upon recovering with timeshift and rebooting, I am encountering the following error

```
[Failed] Failed to mount /home.
[Depend] Dependancy failed for Local File Systems
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to default mode.
```

Obviously, Control-D, rebooting and default mode etc. do not work. I tried timeshift --restore and I get the following error.

[image]

It says

> "Found stale mount for device /dev/nvme0n1p2 at path
> /run/timeshfit/837/backup. \n Unmounted successfully. \n E: Failed to
> remove directory. \n Ret=256"

I *think* the problem is, that it can not mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 to /home. But I am not sure how to fix it.

Would really appreciate some help.

Cheers.

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: upon entering the root (just type password in the emergency mode) I edited /etc/fstab. * There I removed the bits where it said "subvolid=xxx$. E.g from
UUID=xxx-yyy-zzz  /home  btrfs  rw,noatime,compress=zstd:3,ssd,space_cache,commit=120,subvolid=257,subvol=/@home 0 0
to
UUID=xxx-yyy-zzz  /home  btrfs  rw,noatime,compress=zstd:3,ssd,space_cache,commit=120,subvol=/@home 0 0
Save and reboot.
Fixed

- Technically, I had typed mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /home and then I used sudo vim /etc/fsbat. But it should be the same result, unless I am gravely mistaken.

USE ALL AT YOUR OWN RISK :) But it worked fro me.

Much thanks to @Albator78 on the Arch subreddit:
https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/qhb13t/comment/hieiyyk/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3